# ORACLE SQL missing right parenthesis bad syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can't seem to figure out where is the syntax mistake. Even though the query is very simple.

Thanks in advance!

```
UPDATE t_stock
set f_atcid = (select a.id from t_atc a where a.f_code = ' ' where rownum < 2)
where id in (select f_stockid from t_barcode where f_barcode = ' ');
```

Comment: and whats the error message?

Comment: Though is silly mistake I found this to be a common error(having two `where` clauses). I would keep this question on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is two `where` clauses.  Change the second to `and`:

```
UPDATE t_stock
    set f_atcid = (select a.id
                   from t_atc a
                   where a.f_code = ' ' and
----------------------------------------^
                         rownum < 2
                  )
where id in (select f_stockid from t_barcode where f_barcode = ' ' );
```

Comment: What a silly mistake. Everything seems to working fine now. Thanks!